# Стоит ли начинать изучение Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте!
Вот недавно начал изучать язык Ruby. Насколько перспективным является этот язык и стоит ли его продолжать изучать серьёзно?

Comment: Во всяком случае вреда точно не будет.

На мой взгляд очень гибкий и удобный язык.


Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не стоит изучать языки только для практического применения. Когда возникнет реальная потребность программист легко сможет выучить необходимый для практики язык, разобраться с платформой. Выбирайте язык чтобы получить опыт программирования, не обязательно опыт работы.

Как сказал один мудрец:

> A language that doesn't affect the way you think about programming, is not worth knowing.

Если вы нашли что-то интересно в самом Ruby, то конечно лучше изучить его.

Что касается реальной практики то да, Ruby стал широко популярен благодаря Rails, мощному web-фрейворку. Зарабатывать на хлеб этим вполне можно (так например поступаю я). Да, перспективно.

Answer (score 1):

Если для веба, то в случае если уже изучены PHP, Perl, Python (не говоря уже о HTML, CSS, JS), то можно поучить, если, конечно, не требуется по конкретной работе. То же для десктопного применения.

Язык, насколько мне известно, интересный, для общего образования поучить можно, но предложений по работе с ним не очень много.

Comment: Всеми перечисленными технологиями, кроме Perl, владею. 

Вот по поводу востребованности хотелось бы сказать, что Ruby/Ruby on Rails очень востребован работодателями, несмотря на то, что популярность языка оставляет желать лучшего, но это, надеюсь, не повод не изучать его. Думаю, сюда заглядывали все:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/137833/

Comment: Ну, тогда однозначно учить, особенно если есть интерес и желание.